# import_error_application django on python anywhere. I deployed the app on python anywhere but this error is stopping me from going further

Tags: django, pythonanywhere, django-wsgi

import_error_application django on python anywhere. I deployed the app on python anywhere but this error is stopping me from going further. Also is there any standard code for deploying on pythonanywhere without bugs.

```
:/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py:1160: RuntimeWarning: tp_compare didn't return -1 or -2 for exception
:  return _active[_get_ident()]
:Traceback (most recent call last):
:  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 130, in __call__
:    self.error_log_file.logger.exception("Error running WSGI application")
:  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1185, in exception
:    self.error(msg, *args, **kwargs)
:  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1178, in error
:    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
:  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1270, in _log
:    record = self.makeRecord(self.name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func, extra)
:  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1244, in makeRecord
:    rv = LogRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func)

:  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 284, in __init__
:    self.threadName = threading.current_thread().name
:  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1160, in currentThread
:    return _active[_get_ident()]
:  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 122, in __call__
:    app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
:  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 136, in import_error_application
:    raise e
:  File "/home/username/timepass/timepass/settings.py", line 109
//Actually there is no code at line 109
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting an error from a line that doesn't exist, the most likely thing is that you're looking at a traceback generated from an old version of your code and you need to reload your web app to see the correct traceback.